Periodic background task in Flutter with less than a minutr frequency
I have read some tutorials about background with flutter: background_fetch, workmanager and so on.
Their all have the issue that the minimum frequency is 15minutes.
That don't even fullfil the requirements of many application. Spotify runs for hours in the back, as well as youtube or the simple preinstalled countdown app/timer app on my samsung galaxy.
I would have assumed that the Flutter team should have a basic feature or package for background task since it is a very common feature.
Is there something great out there?
I have not look into isolates yet.

What is your use case? In general, you are only allowed to execute code in the background every 15 minutes. There are special cases where the operating system makes exceptions. For example, music and timers. There are also packages for Flutter for these special cases.

Hi @Mäddin, my use case is to run a background task every minute or even less to check if the phone is close to a location and react accordingly. 15 minutes would be useless

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation
https://pub.dev/packages/background_location_tracker
Does one of these plugins fulfill your use case?

And Flutter does not have a "basic feature" for this, because neither iOS nor Android allow frequent background processes apart from exceptions.
